# Warnings making a plot that depends on renderUI and uiOutput in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to reproduce a simple shiny app. In the sibebarPanel there are two SelecInput. The first one selects a dataset (e.g. mtcars and iris). The second one selects one column of the dataset selected in the previous SelecInput. In the mainPanel I try to plot the histogram of this variable.

**ui**

```
ui <-  fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Panel Interactivo de aNálisis Econométrico (PINE)'),
  theme = shinythemes::shinytheme("cosmo"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('dataset', 'Choose Dataset', c('mtcars', 'iris')),
    uiOutput('columns')
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot')
  )
)
```

**server**

```
server <-

  function(input, output){

    mydata = reactive({get(input$dataset)})

    output$columns <- renderUI({

      selectInput('columns2', 'Columns', names(mydata()))
    })
    output$plot <- renderPlot(
      hist(mydata()[,input$columns2])
    )
  }
```

I get the plot but in the console I get the warning 'Error in hist.default: 'x' must be numeric' followed by

```
  166: stop
  165: hist.default
  163: renderPlot
  161: func
  121: drawPlot
  107: <reactive:plotObj>
   91: drawReactive
   78: origRenderFunc
   77: output$plot
    1: runApp
```

no matter the variable or dataset I select. I don't know if it's a normal warning when you work with renderUI, uiOutput and plots or I need to do something to `input$columns2` to solve the warning.

I'm a begginer with shiny. I've read tutorials and threads in here in StackOverflow but I'm rellt stucked. Any help will be apreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Have you tried updating `shiny` and restarting a new session of R? Also, are you sure there isn’t a typo in your code that you fixed when posting? That error most likely means that you’re not properly subsetting your data - I get it it I use `input$columns` instead of `input$columns2`

Comment: @divibisan Thanks for your comment. I have updated shiny package and restarted a new R session but I still getting the same warning. The code posted is a copy&paste from my file. And if I use `hist(mydata()[,input$columns])` instead `hist(mydata()[,input$columns2])` then I get an error and not the plot.

Comment: There is something I don't understand because if I ask for `renderPrint(summary(mydata()[,input$columns2])` using `verbatimTextOutput()` in the main panel everything is fine. I get the warning only when I try to render a plot (even whith ggplot). Thanks again.I'll keep looking why it happens.

Comment: @ChristianGonzalez-Martel that warning occurs because of the time difference when the histogram argument doesn't have data.

Comment: You can see here https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html

Comment: @amrrs Thanks for your comment. I understand that this warning happens until the data of the histogram are loaded. It's nrormal. The only way to manage it is with the validate and need functions. I'll read the article carefully. Thanks